# Point a part of image when coordinates are entered in php

Tags: php, html

i am new to PHP and i would like to know if it is possible when i entered a coordinate x and y it will automatically point out the coordinates in the image?

Just like when searching in google maps, the difference is that in google maps we enter the name of the place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is: `yes`. Please elaborate.

Comment: i'm simulating my own google map sir. for example i have an image then when i enter the x axis and y axis, automatically it will point out the part of that image depending on the x & y axis i've entered.

Comment: It will be difficult for someone to help you; what image are you talking about? Are you building a web application? Are you using a third party component? Can you share a minimum amount of code to show what you are trying to achieve, and what is the information you seek? That will make it possible for the SO community to better help you.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, this is my first time here. a Map Image sir. it is a web application using php